# 90s American live action series set on a space station, with gem implanted in hands dictating who one could marry

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

So I remember this show that was based in a space station (more like a hub with no political affiliations)  some of the main characters were doctors, and the thing today's sticking out to me is that everyone had to have a gem implanted I their hand and the colour of that gem dictated who you could marry/date.

This was a live action series, colour, in America. Started in like the 90s. No idea how long it ran.

Sorry I'm not giving a lot of information.

Edit: So it might be Island City, I'm going to watch the whole thing to make sure, but I really appreciate you guys thinking about this. I guess I can't trust my little kid memories.

Final edit! That was it! Thanks everyone for the help. Convinced that they need to remake it. It was awesome.

Comment: Sorry, live action series, colour, in America. Started in like the 90s. No idea how long it ran.

Comment: Sounds like [Island City](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VKPSMCc0_WI) mixed with something else

Comment: Oh my...that may be it. I'm going to have to watch the whole thing to be sure.

Comment: Don't forget to come back and post it as an answer if it turns out to be the one you're looking for! ;) Also, you can check [other questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q="island+city") about "Island City" (particularly [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q="island+city") - maybe they'll jog your memory.

Comment: Will do. Gonna watch it with my sister since she also remembers bits and pieces of it.

Comment: Damn, really wish I'd seen your edit before digging through IMDB to find the title...the description gave me some 1990's flashbacks that were going to drive me crazy.  I

Comment: Given that there's no accepted answer, or confirmation from the OP, I cannot close this as dupe at this point.

Comment: @Mooz Confirmation is in the last two paragraphs of the question. Granted, that wasn’t the correct practice by the OP.

Comment: @amaranth Oh sorry, missed that. Yeah smash it.

Answer (score 0):

In Logan's Run (film and tv spin off series) the inhabitants of the city had gems in the palm of their hands but it was used to determine when they had reached the end of their lives not who they could marry, I think they all wore different coloured clothing for that

Comment: No the gems did not determine the inhabitants life span. But who they could marry.